# jQuery - Turkish Characters assigned to number keys 1-5 not appearing properly in textarea

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a textarea accept some Turkish characters so that I can directly cut and paste the resulting text to other programs without having to keep changing the Windows keyboard from US-ENGLISH to TURKISH-Q.

I have got it working to a point. But the Numbers are appended to the text area. When I press the "clear textarea" button only then I see my special turkish characters only - all my previous input is erased.  The Keyboard Nos 1-5 have been used to assign the special turkish characters.
Why is e.peventdefault not working, I wonder? and Why do I see my special input after pressing the clear text button? Any help to put it right please?
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Turkish Key input to textarea</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {margin:30px 50px;}
            textarea {font-family:verdana, sans-serif;font-size:16px;}
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <pre>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var nochar="",cced="ç",sced="ş",inodot="ı";ouml="ö",uuml="ü"
                    $('#write').keyup(function (e) {
                        //Key No1
                        if (e.keyCode == 49) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#write').append(cced).show();
                        }
                        //Key No2
                        if (e.keyCode == 50) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#write').append(sced).show();
                        }
                        //Key No3
                        if (e.keyCode == 51) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#write').append(inodot).show();
                        }
                        //Key No4
                        if (e.keyCode == 52) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#write').append(ouml).show();
                        }
                        //Key No5
                        if (e.keyCode == 53) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#write').append(uuml).show();
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </pre>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Input Turkish Characters - Copy and Paste</h1>
        <p>Use keyboard for all other characters.</p>
        <form>
            <textarea id="write"  rows="12" cols="50" style="border:solid navy;"></textarea><br><br>
            <input  type="reset"  value="Clear Box"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<html lang="tr" xml:lang="tr">
```